# Issue with ColdFusion 2018 Query When Enable Null is True

Tags: null, coldfusion, cfml

I have the issue with Coldfusion 2018 when i return my query results, it shows like this

[image]

problem is the null appearing in brackets, this is strange, previous coldfusion versions never showed like this and when the value is null, it is actually throwing null pointer exception issue

any idea, how can i fix it

Comment: Do you use a special database system? An exotic driver, maybe?

Comment: no, what is extic driver, i am sql server 2016

Comment: when you dump `queryname.status`, what do you see in the page?

Comment: Are the brackets actually in the value of that field or is this simply a way of displaying a `null` in the dump?

Comment: they are actually in the field

Answer (score 6):

The issue is in your main question.

> issues with coldfusion query in Coldfusion 2018 ***having enable null equal to true***

**TLDR:** You'll need to update your code to check for and account for `null`s or you should turn that setting off until you can handle them correctly.

**Details:**

https://coldfusion.adobe.com/2018/07/null-support-in-coldfusion-2018/

> `Null` is an important construct in modern programming languages, which
> improves language interoperability with other tech stack and
> programming languages.
>
> Before the 2018 release of ColdFusion, a database null or a null
> returned from an external service was getting converted to empty
> string. Therefore, if you were to code for null or take decisions
> based on null value in your ColdFusion applications, there was no
> inherent way to achieve this.
>
> Imagine a scenario where you want to have an empty string as a column
> value in a database table. Since null is also converted as empty
> string, there was no way to distinguish a null from an empty string.
> This behavior also affected json serialization and deserialization.
>
> Given an actual need for null-based implementation, we decided to
> introduce null as part of language changes in ColdFusion (2018
> release).
>
> Now in your ColdFusion applications, you can assign null to a
> variable, as shown below:
>
> `<cfset price = null>`
>
> You can also use the function isNull to check if a value is null.
>
> `<cfdump var=”# isNull(price)#”> //prints yes`
>
> `<cfif price == null> // resolves to true`
>
> `<cfif price eq null> // resolves to true`

You can turn this on in CF Admin for all applications on the server or you can turn this on at the application level so that only specific applications use the setting.

With this on, your queries are returning `[null]` instead of `[empty string]` when the value of a database column is `null` or an empty string.

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/using-coldfusion-variables/data-types-developing-guide.html

```
<cfscript>
    myquery=querynew("id,name","integer,varchar",[[null,"hello"],[1,"null"],[null,"null"]]);
    writedump(myquery);
    writedump(format="text",var=#myquery#);
</cfscript>
```

- Records 1 and 3 have a `null` for the ID.
- Records 2 and 3 have the string `"null"` for the name.

[image: Example of nulls in CF 2018]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, but this broke my whole code, so probably it means better not to enable this because db will return null and this cannot handled properly unless a common udf or function handles it in different context and used in Application CFC or cfm file to treat them both as separate if nul is enabled and if its not enabled and if enabled what can be excluded and what not